# Looking for an interesting result on the Navier-Stokes equations

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am in my second year of master in Mathematics and one of my courses consists of a reading of *Navier-Stokes Equations* by Roger Temam. We have proven the existence for the weak Stokes and Navier-Stokes (defined on a bounded domain) in a stationary and non-stationary regime using a Galerkin method.

Now I have to do a 2 hours presentation on the subject of my choice (still related to hydrodynamics) and I would like to know if one of you had an idea of something I could talk about. I looked on the internet for an article that could match my critera but all I found was way too advance or too long for what I am looking for. I am looking for a paper that could be presented in two hours, that is accessible to a master student (who has read Temam's book) and that is an important result in the modern understanding of the Navier-Stokes equations (a paper by Leray, Ladyzhenskaya, Fujita-Kato, Lions, ... for example). Could one of you, who has a better knowledge of what has been done in hydrodynamics, give me some advice on this subject?

Comment: （for the interested reader, there are some answers over on the [MO crosspost](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419588/looking-for-an-interesting-result-on-the-navier-stokes-equations))